# How to Use Regular Expression to Look for the something NOT of Certain pattern

Tags: regex, perl

Using Perl style regexp, is it possible to look for something not of certain pattern?

For example, `[^abc]` looks for a SINGLE CHARACTER not `a` nor `b` nor `c`.

But can I specify something longer than a single character?
For example, in the following string, I want to search for the first word which is not a top level domain name and contains no uppercase letter, or perhaps some more complicated rules like having 3-10 characters. In my example, this should be `"abcd"`:

```
net com org edu ABCE abcdefghijklmnoparacbasd abcd
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using negative look-ahead assertions as:

```
^(?!(?:net|com|org|edu)$)(?!.*[A-Z])[a-z]{3,10}$
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/SQ0pP)

Explanation:

```
^                   - Start anchor
$                   - End anchor
(?:net|com|org|edu) - Alternation, matches net or com or org or edu
(?!regex)           - Negative lookahead. 
                      Matches only if the string does not match the regex.
```

So the part `(?!(?:net|com|org|edu)$)` ensures that input is not one of the top level domains.

The part `(?!.*[A-Z])` ensures that the input does not have a upper case letter.

The part `[a-z]{3,10}$` ensures that the input is of length atleast 3 and atmost 10.

Comment: there's a great video that explains look aheads (and some other basic regex) here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/how-to-use-lookaheads-and-lookbehinds-in-your-regular-expressions/

Comment: Better use the complement instead of `.`: `(?![^A-Z]*[A-Z])`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the "not match" operator: !~

So just create your expression and then see that a variable does not match it:

```
if ($var !~ /abc/) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO its easier to do some matching with regexp and some checks with perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = "net com org edu ABCE abcdefghijklmnoparacbasd abcd";

# loop short words (a-z might not be what you want though)
foreach( $s =~ /(\b[a-z]{3,10}\b)/g ){
    print $_, "\n" if is_tpl($_);  
}
```

BTW, there are a lot of top level domains ..

Comment: look ahead assertions or simple negative regexes are more efficent then this

Comment: probably.. unless the simpler reg.exp is a lot faster and there are few "hits".. I guess it often wont matter